# Redirect website folder to subdomain

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect, subdomain

I have 3 websites with this structure

```
Website 1 : domain.com  
Website 2 : domain.com/website-2/something  
Website 3 : domain.com/website-3/something
```

Now i would like to use instead of folder subdomain

```
Website 1 : domain.com  
Website 2 : website-2.domain.com/something  
Website 3 : website-3.domain.com/something
```

So i need to redirect with this htaccess rule

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(website-2.*)$ http://website-2.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L,NC]
RewriteRule ^(website-3.*)$ http://website-3.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L,NC]
```

But i don't know if this is correct because this don't work for **Website 3** the redirect is like this
**website-3.domain.com/website-3/something** instead of
**website-3.domain.com/something**

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you match `(website-2.*)` where `.*` means zero or more of any character (greedy), so also the `/something` part.

You could create 2 groups and check for the `/` like so:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(website\-2)\/?(.*)$ http://website-2.domain.com/$2 [R=301,L,NC]
RewriteRule ^(website\-3)\/?(.*)$ http://website-3.domain.com/$2 [R=301,L,NC]
```

But, since your matches aren't very different, we could wrap them in 1 rule like so:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(website\-(?:2|3))\/?(.*)$ http://$1.domain.com/$2 [R=301,L,NC]
```

where `(?:2|3)` matches `website-2` and `website-3`.

### After your extra information

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule ^(pierre|argile)\/?(.*)$ http://$1.lafaure.info/$2 [R=301,L,NC]
```

In visual

[image]

Comment: OK in fact my real website are 
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(pierre.*)$ http://pierre.lafaure.info/$1 [R=301,L,NC]
RewriteRule ^(argile.*)$ http://argile.lafaure.info/$1 [R=301,L,NC]

Answer (score 0):

No problem if this is like that with a - in the match ?

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule ^(pierre-de-taille|argile-bentonitique)\/?(.*)$ 
http://$1.lafaure.info/$2 [R=301,L,NC]
```

Answer (score 0):

And also if i need to redirect ?

```
lafaure.info/pierre-de taille/something to pierre.lafaure.info/something  
lafaure.info/argile-bentonitique/something to argile.lafaure.info/something
```